# Usar mi ubicación actual como variable para calcular distancia a otro punto

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, javascript-objeto, constantes

Estoy intentando obtener la distancia entre mi ubicación actual (en tiempo real) y un punto/marcador cualquiera. Lo estoy intentando hacer importando geolib, getDistance. (También probé con Haversine pero el problema es el mismo). No puedo.

Haciéndolo con coordenadas fijas funciona siempre pero cuando quiero sustituir una de las dos coordenadas fijas con "Miposicion" como una variable o constante que incluya (lat, lon) no lo puedo hacer. Incluyo parte del código.

```
export default class MyLocation extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   ...
 async componentDidMount() {
   ...
 handleCenter = () => {
   const {
     latitude,
     longitude,
     latitudeDelta,
     longitudeDelta,
   } = this.state.location;
   this.map.animateToRegion({
     latitude,
     longitude,
     latitudeDelta,
     longitudeDelta,
   });
 };

 recalc = async () => {
   clearInterval(this.idInterval);
   let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
     enableHighAccuracy: true,
     accuracy: Location.Accuracy.higher,
     timeout: 5000,
   });
   const { latitude, longitude, speed, accuracy } = location.coords;
   const { coordsBest } = this.state;

   await this.setState((previousState) => ({
     position: accuracy.toFixed(2),
     fill: accuracy.toFixed(1),
     coords: location.coords,
     coordsBest:
       coordsBest.accuracy == null
         ? location.coords
         : coordsBest.accuracy > accuracy
         ? location.coords
         : coordsBest,
     regionInicial: {
       ...previousState.regionInicial,
       latitude: latitude,
       longitude: longitude,
       speed: speed,
     },
   }));
   this.startTimeInterval();
 };

 stopCalcular = async () => {
   clearInterval(this.idInterval);
 };

 componentWillUnmount() {
   clearInterval(this.idInterval);
 }

 render() {
   const { position, fill, coords } = this.state;
   console.log(coords.latitude);
 
 const Miposicion = {latitude: coords.latitude, longitude: coords.longitude}  // no funciona

 const distancia = getDistance(
 { Miposicion },                                      // mi variable en lugar de coordenadas fijas
 { latitude: "51° 31' N", longitude: "7° 28' E" }     // [futuros marcadores]
);
```

Comment: Es decir que el problema no es el cáculo en si, sino como se actualiza esa variable al cargar el módulo con reactjs.

Comment: Qué imprime `console.log(coords.latitude);`?

Comment: Sí @Emeeus es correcto, el cálculo funciona. No reconoce la variable misma (me pide que la defina) o (la defino?) y no reconoce la variable dentro de la formula.

Comment: @AndresGardiol si lo hago dentro de "return (<View>" al final me imprime las coordenadas en tiempo real, pero si quiero llamar a coords.latitude cuando declaro la variable no las reconoce.